# UIPopoverController presented modally doesn't work in iOS 5

Tags: ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller, ios5, ipad-2

First of all, can we talk about iOS 5 here? Or is it still under NDA? 
If we can't talk about it, just ignore my question.

By testing my app with an iPad with iOS 5 installed I discovered a problem with my "modal" popover: This can be closed by tapping outside of it, in other words, it's not modal! I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

A view controller opens the popover with this code:

```
AddProjectViewController *addProjectViewController = [[AddProjectViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
[addProjectViewController setDelegate:self];

UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:addProjectViewController];
[addProjectViewController release];

CGRect popoverFrame = [sender frame];

UIPopoverController *tempPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navController];
[tempPopover presentPopoverFromRect:popoverFrame inView:[self view] permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
self.currentPopover = tempPopover;
[tempPopover release];
[navController release];
```

The view controller that's inside of the popover has this line in it's viewDidLoad.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self setModalInPopover:YES];

    // Do other stuff
}
```

Is there anything missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found it. The setModalInPopover assignment must be inside of the viewDidAppear method of the embedded view controller for the popover to be modal:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [self setModalInPopover:YES];
}
```

Comment: Seems like a bug to me. I needed to put `[self setModalInPopover:[self isModalInPopover]];` in the viewDidAppear method, as I'm setting this value externally in the code which creates the view controller.

Answer (score 1):

The approved answer will work if you are using a custom view controller that knows the view is going to be a in a popover.  However, if you are using a generic view controller created programmatically or a view controller whose `viewDidAppear` method you do not have the ability to override for whatever reason, you can also implement the `UIPopoverControllerDelegate` protocol in a class, set the popover delegate to that class and return NO, in the `popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover`.

Example

In some class that implements UIPopoverControllerDelegate:

```
- (BOOL) popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *) popoverController {
    return NO;
}
```

In the code that creates your popover controller:

```
UIPopoverController * pc = initialize and setup 

pc.delegate = instance of class that impleements UIPopoverControllerDelegate
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the `modalInPopover` property of the navigation controller? This is the view controller that is actually "owned" by the popover, so I would expect that the popover uses its `modalInPopover` property to determine whether it is modal or not.

Perhaps `UINavigationController` did pass this on to its currently visible child view controller in iOS 4.x.

Comment: You are right, it makes sense that it should work if I set the modalInPopover property of the navigation controller. But it doesn't work that way. I found the solution, though. I'll post it soon, it might help others.