# What are Anchor and Passthrough used for in popover segues?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, segue

In Xcode, a Popover segue has two connection fields named Anchor and Passthrough. What are they used for?
[image]

Answer (score 61):

These are properties of the `UIPopoverController`, not the segue.  Thats why if you look at the documentation for the `UIStoryboardPopoverSegue`, you won't find these two properties.

The anchor is telling the `UIPopoverController` where to point its arrow.

The passthrough is an array of views that the user can interact with while the `UIPopoverController` is displayed.

The documentation is here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipopovercontroller

and the section going over the passthrough views is here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipopovercontroller/1624654-passthroughviews

Comment: @iDeveloper: A popover has an arrow attached to the window that give the user a reference to what caused the popover window to come into being. So, you click on a button labeled "login" and a login form opens, you want the arrow to point at the button so the user can clearly see the consequence of their action. The arrow can be left, right, up, or down.

Answer (score 2):

UIPopoverController seems to have been deprecated recently. However, I still see Anchor and Passthrough fields in the storyboard segue inspector.