# How to show segue from bottom of the screen

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I created a segue between two controllers(A, B). In controller A, I am using "performSegueWithIdentifier" method to show controller B's view. However, I want to add an animation on presenting the B. I want it to show/hide from the bottom of the screen. How should I do this?

Comment: What kind of segue is it? Push/show, or present/modal?

Comment: Simply do a custom presentation transition animation, using UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I achieved this using **Present As Popover** when choosing the kind of segue in **Attributes Inspector**. Make sure you point your anchor to the view controller you are segueing from, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614949/what-are-anchor-and-passthrough-used-for-in-popover-segues) answer was pretty helpful.

Make sure you give it an identifier (using this identifier below) and use the typical perform segue code whenever you wish to perform the segue:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { 
    [unowned self] in
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Identifier", sender: self)
}
```

*Make sure you replace "Identifier" string with a string of your own segue identifier.*