# drop down menu on navigation bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

In android, there is action bar with drop down menu, an example is the old Gmail app in Android:

[image]

As you see above, when the three-dots is clicked, a drop down menu is shown.

**My Questions:**

1. I am wondering, if I want to implement the same three-dots button which shows drop down menu in iOS with Navigation Controller, how to do it?
2. If it is not a common thing to do in iOS, what is the equivalent in iOS?

(I still want to implement it in my iOS project though)

Comment: There's no built-in widget in iOS.

Answer (score 1):

The closest I can think of is UIPopOverController for iPad.
You can put a tableview in a "popover".

[Sample popover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YeA1.png)

For iPhone Popover visit this tutorial

https://richardallen.me/2014/11/28/popovers.html

Answer (score 1):

What was answered before is not true anymore. Now there are context menus.

With iOS13 there was `UIMenu` introduced and with iOS14 `UIBarButtonItem` has a `menu` property for that you can set a `UIMenu`. The menu you set there, will pop up when tapping the `UIBarButtonItem`. (see also https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibarbuttonitem/3601188-menu)

You do not need to set any other action on the `UIBarButtonItem` (see line before last line in my sample code, `action` is `nil`).

Here is an example for having a `rightBarButtonItem` triggering a menu with four items.

```swift
let menuHandler: UIActionHandler = { action in
    print(action.title)
}

let barButtonMenu = UIMenu(title: "", children: [
    UIAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Identify Plant", comment: ""), image: UIImage(systemName: "viewfinder"), handler: menuHandler),
    UIAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Plant's diary", comment: ""), image: UIImage(systemName: "books.vertical"), handler: menuHandler),
    UIAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Plant's notifications", comment: ""), image: UIImage(systemName: "bell"), handler: menuHandler),
    UIAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Remove plant", comment: ""), image: UIImage(systemName: "trash"), handler: menuHandler)
])

navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Manage", style: .plain, target: self, action: nil)
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.menu = barButtonMenu

// or using the initializer
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Manage", image: nil, primaryAction: nil, menu: barButtonMenu)
```

My answer is based on this great sample code article: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/customizing_your_app_s_navigation_bar

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in UI component for this in iOS, and it's not widely used in apps.

But when I need to implement it I usually use [AssistoLab DropDown](https://github.com/AssistoLab/DropDown), it's a very easy to use, well-documented and stable library.

Answer (score 0):

That not an iOS thing. BUT that been said, the best approach would be to have do a PopOver. [Here theres a good answer for a PopOver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20256641/7668778)

[Here theres a framework that do all the work for you.](https://github.com/corin8823/Popover)

[Any here theres another good answear with a popOver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24635744/how-to-present-popover-properly-in-ios-8)

Also you can just create a simple View. And when u display it, just do an animation on the view height constraint to animate the growing.